# wordpress plugin development to add in htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm developing a plugin in wordpress it needs to add htaccess code I used insert_with_markers it's writing to htaccess but it adds it on the bottom of the htaccess file I need to add a code on top of all the htaccess file. How do I do this?

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
SO is a platform where you can get a good suggestion regarding your problems.  But for that, you need to be more specific about what you are asking?  what have you done so far?  Before asking please see the suggested SO question and take a look at them. Still, you did not find a solution then you can ask a question here.

Comment: When asking questions about WordPress development and administration, you are likely to get better answers if you ask the questions on [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 0):

You have to **prepend** the htaccess rules that you want to add to the exisiting rules. Something like the:

```
function my_htaccess_contents( $rules )
{
    $my_content = <<<EOD
    \n # BEGIN My Added Content
    # Protect wpconfig.php
    <Files wp-config.php>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Deny from all
     </Files>
# END My Added Content\n
EOD;
return $my_content . $rules;
}
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'my_htaccess_contents');
```

Comment: I tried this it did no change on my htaccess file. $my_content needs to be a string?